# Access SQL - Select Rows from Table1 where any column in Table2 is different

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to find a more efficient way to perform a query to:

Select all rows from Table1 where any column in an identically designed Table2 (in another database) is different.
This query will be used for an UPDATE query to update Table1 with any changes in Table2.

The way I've done it at the moment is:

```
SELECT T1.* 

FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table2 IN 'FilePath') T2 ON 
T1.ID = T2.ID

WHERE 
T1.Column1 <> T2.Column1 OR
T1.Column2 <> T2.Column2 OR
...
T1.Column67 <> T2.Column67
```

Now this works but is understandably slow on 67 columns (~ 40 Seconds - 1 Minute) - and this select query will then be the resulting query that Updates Table1 daily

So if there is a really simple way of doing this that I've overlooked, i'd appreciate some insight

Comment: is it feasible to add a date/time to each record for when it was last updated, and select the once where the time in T2 is later than the time in T1?

Comment: One other idea - is it feasible to delete from T2 where it is the same as T1, then use the edited T2 for your updates?

Comment: The date/time is a no go as T1 is a read only linked table - the second idea could work, although as T1 is read-only - I would have to insert all into a middle table, delete all the *same* records and update on the result set - but i'm unsure if that is more efficient than just selecting in the way I have done it above?

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` can be used for [The shortest, fastest, and easiest way to compare two tables...](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx) in Access:

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ID
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Table1
    UNION ALL                                 --< Have identical records duplicated
    SELECT * FROM Table2
  ) Combined
  GROUP BY ID, Column1, Column2, ... Column67 --< Compare significant columns
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1                         --< Take unique records only
) Different ON Table1.ID = Different.ID;
```

**Please note**: As @[HansUp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77335/hansup) has pointed out Microsoft Access documentation stipulates that only up to 10 fields can be used in [GROUP BY Clause](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/GROUP-BY-Clause-84eeb766-25d2-4aa1-8eea-002bb65ef3a0). Although I have found no issues grouping by all 68 columns in Access 2016 please note that this apparently is an undocumented feature and must be used with caution.

Comment: Have you tested this?  I doubt Access will accept 68 fields in a `GROUP BY` clause.  Microsoft's [GROUP BY Clause](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/GROUP-BY-Clause-84eeb766-25d2-4aa1-8eea-002bb65ef3a0) page suggests the limit is 10.

Comment: @HansUp For compatibility columns can be concatenated into one string for `GROUP BY` like [C. White](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37415016/5690722) suggested though that would likely impair performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It seems I misinterpreted the page I linked.  Just tested in Access 2010 with 11 fields in the `GROUP BY` and Access didn't complain.  I'll take your word about 68.  :-)

Comment: @HansUp I can not see how that could be misinterpreted. The documentation is quite explicit about it: [GROUP BY Clause (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177905(v=office.12).aspx). Maybe it has been fixed in Jet engine recently and has not been reflected in documentation yet. Anyway, thank you for the fair warning of apparently **undocumented feature** being used.

Comment: I misinterpreted *"The names of **up to 10** fields used to group records"* to mean no more than 10.  That actually seems like a reasonable interpretation to me; but wrong.

Comment: @HansUp I would "misinterpret" it exactly the same way should I be reading documentation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It may be more efficient to concatenate all of the fields together, and then do a single comparison.

This VBA should get you a more-or-less workable piece of SQL:

```
Public Function CompareTableSQL(Table1 as String, Table2 as String, Optional Table2Path as String = vbNullString) as String
  Dim Table1Field as string, Table2Field as string
  Dim tdf as DAO.TableDef, db as DAO.Database, f as DAO.Field2
  Set db = CurrentDB
  Set tdf = db.TableDefs(Table1)
  For each f in tdf.Fields
    Table1Field = Table1Field & " & ""+"" & CStr(nz([" & Table1 & "].[" & f.name & "],""NULL""))"
    Table2Field = Table2Field & " & ""+"" & CStr(nz([" & Table2 & "].[" & f.name & "],""NULL""))"
  Next
  ' Extracting the primary key and joining on it is relatively easy, _
    but that's not really the point of this, so I'm leaving it out.
  SQL = "SELECT [" & Table1 & "].* FROM [" & Table1 & "] " & vbcrlf & _
        "LEFT JOIN [" & Table2 & "] ON [" & Table1 & "].ID = [" & Table2 & "].ID " & vbcrlf
        "WHERE " & vbcrlf & _
        Table1Field & "<>" & Table2Field & ";"
End Function
```